# Concrete Driveway Traction

Tags: concrete, driveway

I park my vehicle on a steep portion of the driveway and recently it slipped trying to go back up the driveway. Ended up needing a tug from another vehicle in order to regain traction. The driveway wasn't brushed properly when it was put-in.

I was wondering if there's a solution to just fixing where the vehicle is parked to gain traction from a mostly smooth concrete surface? I've looked into acid-etching, speed-bump, rubber mats potentially applying a slip paint product. Just unsure if anyone has done this exterior and the results.

It's not my daily driver so I'm not opposed to the rubber mats option; just couldn't find anyone using them in my research.

Update from questions: about 45 degree slope and my tires aren't old, but may benefit with more traction focused tires. The driveway was just never brushed so it's generally slippery. I imagine weight in the back in these situations would help.

Comment: I have a two wheel pick up truck.  Fantastic with a hay bale in the back and will pull a full hay wagon like nothing.  Empty and a tiny bit of ice/mud and it is useless on flat ground.

Comment: Pictures? What slope (angle)?

Comment: Front, rear, or 4 wheel drive train? Climbing in forward or reverse?

Comment: Do you want to park in the same place all the time?  I imagine you have no problem if you get a run at it, only from a standing stop.  If rare times parking there, then rubber/traction mats might be enough.

Comment: It slipped when dry? Or it was snow covered/icy?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it's about 45. I'll take a pic in the daylight

Comment: @greghill it's rwd. I was going forward. I park it usually downhill with bed facing downard as water stays in the bed if I don't.

Comment: @LarryBud it was a hard rain here in San Diego and there was some mud that had went downhill under the tires

Comment: @crip659 parking is a bit tight so I would prefer to park in the same place generally.

Comment: Rain water in the bed will provide weight that will help with traction. Once you're on level ground, accelerating will cause the water to drain out of the bed under the tailgate.

Comment: You have a driveway 45*? No way. In CA, the largest grade can be 25%, which is 14 degrees.

Comment: @LarryBud I did some measurements and you're right so thanks for correcting me. It comes out to 14-16 degrees with a digital level I used this week. Still technically a little above in areas from the "largest", but pretty close

Answer (score 3):

You can bring in a pavement groover if your driveway is big and steep.  For the DIY crowd, you can use a large angle grinder to grind diamond grid lines, though this is incredibly messy and somewhat dangerous, or you can rent a concrete engraving tool that appears to be something like a concrete saw on wheels.

You could also just cut out sections of the concrete and replace them with asphalt or gravel, which would improve traction.

You might even get away with using a diamond grinding bit on an angle grinder to roughen the surface of the steep sections

Or you could just go get new tires for your car.

Comment: This.  Concrete pavement—especially things like bridges—is typically grooved, to allow water to be pushed into the grooves—basically like your car tires—so that the high parts can provide traction.  Residential concrete pavement is typically only brushed to provide high points for traction.  Do whatever is practical for you to create high and low points.